R: Dynamic function specification
I'm using a choice modelling package (apollo) that has a function that needs to be specified as part of the model input parameters.
I want to dynamically specify a function such that in each iteration of a loop, part of the function is specified with a different subset of parameters. But there's a couple of constraints. First, I can't change the arguments the function accepts. Second, the function uses attach.
I think there should be a hack but I'm not sure what it is! This is where I've got to so far:
for(var in c("Age", "Female") {
  x <- parse(text = c("delta_a","gamma_Age_a*Age","gamma_Female_a*Female") %>%
              str_subset(var, negate = TRUE) %>%
              paste(collapse = "+"))
  
  assign("dynamic_fun", function(args){
    x
})  
}

Here, in each iteration of the loop, the parsed expression should be as follows:
[1] expression(delta_a+gamma_Female_a*Female)
[2] expression(delta_a+gamma_Age_a*Age)

But it doesn't work because x in the function is just x rather than an unevaluated expression. In the existing function, the expression is specified like so:
existing_fun <- function(args){
...
    V=list()
    V[["first"]] = delta_a + gamma_Age_a*Age + gamma_Female_a*Female 
...
}

But I can't see how it's possible to recreate this structure while filtering the formula elements...
The desired outcome is a loop that creates a set of functions like this:
fun <- function(args){
...
    V=list()
    V[["first"]] = delta_a + gamma_Female_a*Female 
...
}

fun <- function(args){
...
    V=list()
    V[["first"]] = delta_a + gamma_Age_a*Age 
...
}

The name of the function doesn't need to change, only the expression it contains

It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

It's difficult to work out the bigger picture of what you are trying to do here; I suspect whatever it is, there is a much better way than looping through a character vector and creating / assigning a new function each time. Do you have a fixed list of args that dynamic_fun is going to use? Can't you have the text strings among the arguments to your dynamic function and handle the calculation inside the dynamic function depending on what strings it is called with rather than writing a new function each time?

This gives a list of expressions: v <- c("Female", "Age"); L <- lapply(v, function(v) as.expression(str2lang(sprintf("delta_a + gamma_%s_a * %s", v, v))))  It may be that you don't need the as.expression depending on what is needed.

@MrFlick I've edited to be more specific about what I want as an output

@AllanCameron one of the constraints is I can't modify the args for the existing function. I agree it would be much easier if I could. The function is part of a choice modelling package (http://www.apollochoicemodelling.com/). There are lots of embedded checks that make it very difficult to modify the structure of the function, this specific function (existing_fun - not real name) is only designed for the content of the function to be modified according to the model specification. I want to edit the function to work as part of a loop that implements an automated covariate selection procedure.

The combination eval(parse(…)) is almost never the best solution. What’s better depends on what exactly you want to accomplish. From your answer further down it looks like what you’re actually looking for is a function generator (aka. function factory), i.e. a function that returns a function: f = function (var) { force(var); function (args) {… V = list(); V$first = delta_a + gama_Age_a * get(var, envir = .GlobalEnv) … } } should do the trick.

@KonradRudolph thanks, I never heard of function factories before. If you make this an answer I'll accept it

A dynamic formula could be handed over like this:
fun <- function(args, ...){
  further_args <- list(...)
  V=list()
  V[["first"]] <- further_args$my_formula
  
  ## test:
  lm(formula = V[['first']], data = mtcars)
}


generate a formula and pass it to fun:

fun(foo = pi, bar = 'a',
    my_formula = as.formula(sprintf('mpg ~ %s + %s', 'cyl', 'disp'))
    )

## Call:
## lm(formula = further_args$my_formula, data = mtcars)
## 
## Coefficients:
## (Intercept)          cyl         disp  
##    34.66099     -1.58728     -0.02058  


Thanks but one of the constraints is that the function args cannot change (including adding in the ellipsis)

Strange. Name and content of the args argument shouldn't be affected by passing in optional ones. Likewise, the optional args (...) should be ignored unless explicitly accessed by any function.

the length of arguments changes, which doesn't pass checks by subsequent functions in the package

So this seems to work:
for(var in c("Age", "Female")) {
  
  dynamic_fun <- paste0(
    "existing_fun <- function(args){ 
    V=list()
    V[[\"first\"]] = ", c("delta_a","gamma_Age_a*Age","gamma_Female_a*Female") %>%
             str_subset(var, negate = TRUE) %>%
             paste(collapse = "+"),
    "}"
  )
  eval(parse(text = dynamic_fun))
}

